# multiple file upload validation through array in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

The below represents my script code

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function (){    
            $("#checkfields").click(function (){

                var file1=$("#file1").val();
                if(file1){                        
                    var file_size=$('#file1')[0].files[0].size;
                    if(file_size<2097152){
                        var ext = $('#file1').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();                            
                        if($.inArray(ext,['jpg','jpeg','gif'])===-1){
                            alert("Invalid file extension");
                            return false;
                        }

                    }else{
                        alert("Screenshot size is too large.");
                        return false;
                    }                        
                }else{
                    alert("fill all fields..");         
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

The below represents my code

```
<form action="checkmobile.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal"> 
<div class="form-group">
                        <label for="element-13" class="control-label col-lg-2">Add Screenshots</label>
                        <div class="input-group">                            
                            <input type="file" id="file1" name="file[]" class="btn" multiple="multiple">
                        </div>
                    </div>
<div class="form-group">

                                <input type="submit" id="checkfields" class="btn btn-primary  col-lg-offset-2" value="Add">
                                <button class="btn btn-default col-lg-offset-1">Cancel</button>
                            </div>
                </form>
```

Now I want to know how to use array in jQuery for validating all selected files under the input.

If I select one image and one video then it must check validation for image and video. first it will validate image if image is ok then it will reject the video by invalid extension.

i want to validation for all files while submitting the button and if image not valid then return error and if there is video selected with image then also it return error.

please help.

Comment: Although I have resolved your problem but before posting the answer just want to confirm if you want upload only images...

Comment: Ya only images i want to upload

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using below code -

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function (){    
        $("#checkfields").click(function (){
            //var modelname=$("#inputmodelname").val();
            for (var i = 0; i < $("#file1").get(0).files.length; ++i) {
                var file1=$("#file1").get(0).files[i].name;

                if(file1){                        
                    var file_size=$("#file1").get(0).files[i].size;
                    if(file_size<2097152){
                        var ext = file1.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();                            
                        if($.inArray(ext,['jpg','jpeg','gif'])===-1){
                            alert("Invalid file extension");
                            return false;
                        }

                    }else{
                        alert("Screenshot size is too large.");
                        return false;
                    }                        
                }else{
                    alert("fill all fields..");         
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

It validates all the selected files individually. I have commented your modelname variable line and in 'if' condition as i couldn't find any element related to it in the HTML.

Comment: It redirects if i dont select any file which instead i want alert

Comment: You can put condition for it that if length of selection is zero then show alert.